# Share execution among several tasks in GCD?

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, task-queue

I have an async function that synchronizes the network and database from the last call, then returns the results. There are several callers from different threads that calls this function.

Instead of executing and serving the request per call, I'd like to queue up the tasks while the async function runs, then flush out the queue so the next set of tasks can be queued up.

Here's what I came up so far:

```
extension DataWorker {
    // Handle simultanuous pull requests in a queue
    private static let pullQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "DataWorker.remotePull")
    private static var pullTasks = [((SomeType) -> Void)]()
    private static var isPulling = false

    func remotePull(completion: ((SomeType) -> Void)?) {
        DataWorker.pullQueue.async {
            if let completion = completion {
                DataWorker.pullTasks.append(completion)
            }

            guard !DataWorker.isPulling else { return }
            DataWorker.isPulling = true

            self.store.remotePull { result in
                print("Remote pull executed")

                DataWorker.pullQueue.async {
                    let tasks = DataWorker.pullTasks
                    DataWorker.pullTasks.removeAll()
                    DataWorker.isPulling = false

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        tasks.forEach { $0(result) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is how I'm testing it, which I expect exactly 100 iterations but only a couple of `remotePull` executions:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100) { iteration in
    self.dataWorker.remotePull { _ in
        print("Iteration: \(iteration)")
    }
}
```

Is this approach even accurate, or a more elegant or efficient way of achieving this shared task approach?

Comment: As aside bar note: "Is there a more elegant or efficient way of achieving this shared task approach?" working with *Operations* and *Operation Queues* could be more appropriate (easier) for such a task...

Comment: Use DispatchGroup?

Comment: If you have code that works but for which you are soliciting feedback, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a more appropriate forum.

Comment: If the same result is shared with multiple requesters what you can do is have a singleton make the network call and post results and have the requesters take a semaphore which is given when the network call completes.

Comment: @PriceRingo - Just because you have multiple requesters, I wouldn't necessarily jump to singleton pattern. There are tons of reasons why one shouldn't use singletons. If anything, I'd suggest going the other direction. As Apple points out, we should embrace dependency injection. Plus, why is this `DataWorker` using `static`s at all? What if he introduced multiple stores in his app later down the road. Statics and, worse, singletons are the sort of thing that seem super convenient when you first start a project, but can bite you later as your project expands.

Comment: @Rob - You are absolutely right about global singletons and dependency injection. I was wrong. But there is still the need for single responsibility. Whether you inject the single object responsible for network requests or its test mock.